# Recursively Replace character until condition met in php?

Tags: php, recursion, match

An unknown string that can have one or more "-". Example:

```
23ys-824384-hgg32-324-2444h
```

I am trying to find possible matches with another unknown string that can have less "-" than the original string. They need the same characters, though.

For example, `23ys824384-hgg32-324-2444h` is a match, but `23ys84384-hgg32-324-2444h` isn't (missing '2').

I am using `similar_text` for the matching (because I need relative matches too).

I can do a series of if-statements to get the job done, but these can be many. So I am wondering if someone can see a recursive way of doing it (which I am assuringly not seeing). Basically, a way that 'tries' all of the different combinations of that string without the "-". So:

```
23ys824384-hgg32-324-2444h
23ys824384hgg32-324-2444h
23ys824384hgg32324-2444h
23ys824384hgg323242444h
23ys-824384hgg32-324-2444h
23ys-824384hgg32324-2444h
23ys-824384hgg323242444h
etc.
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `-`s from both strings and compare with `===`?

Comment: You are correct and I feel dumb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove all the `-` from each string and then compare:

```
str_replace('-', '', $string1) == str_replace('-', '', $string2)
```